# displaying FEM Data in C++

Tags: c++, qt, colormap

I have a question related how to display with QcustomPlot Colormap FEM data.
The data has the following form:

```
X                  Y              Z
 0.000000   0.000000    0.000020
 0.000000   0.010769    0.003000
 0.010769   0.000000    0.000400
 0.000000   0.041683    0.000050
 0.020058   0.020058    0.003000
 0.040024   0.000000    0.001000
 0.000000   0.072596    0.001000
 0.035689   0.035689    0.000030
 0.069279   0.000000    0.000200
 0.000000   0.134423    0.000200
```

Since the distribution along the axis X and Y is not constant, I don't know how create the matrixes using the

```
colorMap->data()->cellToCoord(xIndex, yIndex, &x, &y);
colorMap->data()->setCell(xIndex, yIndex, z);
```

If somebody has a suggestion to use other type of library, please post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of cellToCoord you should use coordToCell which transforms plot coordinates given by key and value to cell indices of QCPColorMapData instance.

```
colorMap->data()->coordToCell(x, y, &xIndex, &yIndex);
colorMap->data()->setCell(xIndex, yIndex, z);
```

Comment: How can I determine how many xindex and yIndex coordonates do I need?

Comment: It depends on the amount of precision you want. If you want to have a colormap with higher resolution you should have more cells in your map. But i think you don't need more that 2000 cells per axis. Because it is probably higher that the number of pixels in your monitor.

Comment: I did as you wrote above, but now I have a strip like the codebar. The data is not on xy axis, only on the x axis.

Answer (score 0):

when you put:

```
  colorMap->data()->coordToCell(x, y, &xIndex, &yIndex);
```

you modify the index of the "for".
I put a extra index and solve the isue.

```
nt xI=0;
int yI=0;
for (int xIndex=0; xIndex<nx; ++xIndex, xI++)
  {
    for (int yIndex=0; yIndex<ny; ++yIndex, yI++)
   {
    colorMap->data()->coordToCell(x[xIndex], y[yIndex], &xI, &yI); 
    colorMap->data()->setCell(xI, yI, z[xI+yI]);
   }
}
```